# sparklyr - No FileSystem for scheme

Tags: java, r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm trying to use sparklyr API for Apache Spark locally on Windows, but I'm stuck on this error.

I have 2 Disks (C: and F:). Please help me.

## Spark Error: `java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: F`

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)
```

output

````
## Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: F
##  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584)
##  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
##  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
##  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
##  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
##  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
##  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1686)
##  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:598)
##  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:395)
##  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:430)
##  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:422)
##  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
##  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
##  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
##  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
##  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
##  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
##  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
##  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:422)
##  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:206)
##  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
##  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
##  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
## 
## Driver stacktrace:
##  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
##  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
##  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
##  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
##  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
##  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
##  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
##  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
##  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
##  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
##  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
##  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
##  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
##  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
##  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
##  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
##  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
##  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
##  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
##  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
##  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
##  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
##  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
##  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
##  at sparklyr.Utils$.collectColumnString(utils.scala:59)
##  at sparklyr.Utils$.collectColumn(utils.scala:73)
##  at sparklyr.Utils.collectColumn(utils.scala)
##  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
##  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
##  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
##  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
##  at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:94)
##  at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:89)
##  at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:55)
##  at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:49)
##  at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
##  at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
##  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
##  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
##  at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
##  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
##  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
##  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
##  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
##  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
##  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
##  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
##  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
##  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
##  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
##  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
##  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
##  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
##  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
## Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: F
##  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584)
##  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
##  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
##  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
##  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
##  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
##  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1686)
##  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:598)
##  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:395)
##  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:430)
##  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:422)
##  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
##  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
##  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
##  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
##  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
##  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
##  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
##  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:422)
##  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.s
```

# Session Info


```r
sessionInfo()
```

```
## R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
## Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
## Running under: Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 (build 9600)
## 
## locale:
## [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
## [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
## [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
## [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
## [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] dplyr_0.5.0    sparklyr_0.5.2
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] Rcpp_0.12.8     knitr_1.15.1    magrittr_1.5    xtable_1.8-2   
##  [5] R6_2.2.0        stringr_1.1.0   httr_1.2.1      tools_3.3.2    
##  [9] parallel_3.3.2  config_0.2      DBI_0.5-1       withr_1.0.2    
## [13] htmltools_0.3.5 yaml_2.1.14     assertthat_0.1  rprojroot_1.1  
## [17] digest_0.6.11   tibble_1.2      shiny_0.14.2    base64enc_0.1-3
## [21] evaluate_0.10   mime_0.5        rmarkdown_1.2   stringi_1.1.2  
## [25] backports_1.0.4 jsonlite_1.2    httpuv_1.3.3
````

Comment: I just reinstalled and everything went fine. =P

Comment: What did you reinstalled? I'm facing the exact same issue... Do you mind sharing your versions?

Comment: @Ahmet I had spark 1.6.x and hadoop 2.6 installed. So I uninstalled both and instaled spark 2.0.x and hadoop 2.7! Everything inside R with sparklyr package.